# How to implement GDPR Right to erasure with AWS Timestream

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-timestream

In an application that collects data from IoT devices from multiple customer in a single AWS Timestream table, what if a customer leaves and requests all of its data to be deleted, according to GDPR's right to erasure?

Timestream doesn't support deleting records, only updating them.

Possible solutions we came up so far:

- update all records of the customer with zero values
- use table per customer and then delete the whole table (problematic with large number of customers)
- don't actually delete the data, but make it not relatable to the customer anymore (probably not GDPR compliant anyway)

Are there any other options here? Or is there no solution and we have to dump Timestream altogether and use a different product that supports deletes?

Comment: Well, storing PII into Timestream is not a good practice. Dimensions should have limited cardinality and storing user ID (usually a UUID) could be a bad-practice (as it can increase indefinitely). If you're storing more than the ID this cardinality issue will get even worst. I suggest rethinking your architecture and DB solution altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One other alternative is to use [data retention](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/storage.html) to delete the data in Timestream after a period of time you define.

[GDPR](https://gdpr.eu/right-to-be-forgotten/) mentions that you need to delete the data after 1 month (it seems you can have 2 more month but then you need to inform the user that data deletion would take longer).

Keeping data in Timestream can become expensive. I usually store the data in Timestream (short retention) and S3. I use Timestream for fast analytics or near real time dashboarding. I use S3 for adhoc query, ML or historical dashboarding.